# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease' flutter build error

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

output after building apk:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

here is my build.gradle file in the app directory:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXX.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.2.8"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

        signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           profile {
                matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
            }
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }


}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my build.gradle in the android directory:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

how can I solve this issue, I tried upgrading gradle versions but nothing worked and also updated all my packages still the same. Any help is appreciated - my flutter version is 2.8.1.

Comment: Post your build files

Comment: @JustInCoding, I added the build.gradle files as requested.

Comment: *I hope this solution help you*
<https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824927/17797499>

Comment: Add the version of the firebase-analytics plugin.

Comment: Now it shows this error: 
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
    Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update D:\xxxxxx\xxxx\android\build.gradle:   
    ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>

Comment: @anassnaoushi  update this on buildscript{ ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' }

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Firebase in my project and got the same error when trying to make a release and I went in android/app/build.gradle and I added this, and it worked fine:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```